# matplotlib : plot in semilogx while displaying the actual values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to print a `semilogx` graph, only the x-axis should display the values contained in `xdata` what I do is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_stuff(xdata, ydata):
    """ 
    """
    plt.clf()
    # titles and stuff ... 
    plt.semilogx(xdata, ydata)

    plt.xticks(xdata) # this line won't do the work

    plt.show()
```

All I get is a graph that along the x-axis displays the values `10^0 ... 10^n`. Is there a way to correct this ?

Comment: :Can you add a working example please?

Comment: or an example of your data?

Comment: If I understand well, I think you need to change the ticks and the tick labels

Comment: Try `plt.xticks(xdata, xdata)` to also set the labels

Comment: @fhdrsdg worked like a charm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [the `pyplot.xticks()` doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) shows, the first argument to `xticks()` is the tick locations, the second is the tick labels. Therefore, `plt.xticks(xdata)` only changes the tick locations, but does not put the tick labels there too.
Because you want the locations and the labels to be the same, you can simply use:

```
plt.xticks(xdata, xdata)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could this be what you are looking for?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_stuff(xdata, ydata):
    """ 
    """
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.semilogx(xdata, ydata)

    ax.set_xticks(xdata)
    ax.set_xticklabels(xdata)

    plt.show()
```